# Firebase iOS project

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I have yesterday added Firebase iOS project in my console and enabled the crashlytics after that only loading is appearing not sure it's firebase problem or something is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Did you crash the app as mentioned in the screenshot? you will need to build and run the app, then stop Xcode, run the app directly in the device and then crash it. Then restart the app, Crashlytics will send the crash report when restarting the app after a crash.

Comment: I had tried to send the logs still here it is not showing